# How to make a fixed element move when accordion is triggered?

Tags: accordion, css-position

example http://www.londonsitedesign.co.uk/test.html

On this page my menu is situated in the bottom left, fixed position.

The list on the page opens hidden divs using the the jQuery accordion.

How can the menu move down when the hidden divs are revealed to allow the right amount of space needed for each individual div?

Comment: If your page is not going to be much more complex than the example link, is there any reason you cannot make the menu one of the accordion elements?

Comment: It is more complicated than the example I have given. I have simplified it for this question.

Comment: do other elements on the page need to adjust with the accordion movement? I think if the menu is going to be aligned below the accordion list and needs to be moved up and down that regardless of other elements it should just be part of the accordion. The only other feasible option I can think of would be to make the menu a sticky footer? I know that is not really what you were asking for but could that be an option?